# Como hacer esta función con jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dependiendo el importe que trae `importe_base` tiene que actuar de un modo o de otro, pero solo consigo hacer funcionar el de menor a 50€ y el de mayor a 50€.

Al final tiene que ser:

Si no llega a 50€ (No hay descuento)
Si es igual o mayor a 50€ pero menor a 99€ (Descuento de un 5%)
Y por último si es igual o mayor a 100€ (Descuento de un 100%)

```js
var importe_base = 105

if(importe_base <= 49){
    descuento = 0;
    $('.tipoDescuento').html('Nada');
    console.log("no hace nada");
}else if(importe_base > 50 < 99){
    var calculo50 = importe_base * 5/100;
    descuento = calculo50;
    $('.tipoDescuento').html('(-5%)');
    console.log("hace el 5");
}else if(importe_base >= 100){
    var calculo100 = importe_base * 10/100;
    descuento = calculo100;
    $('.tipoDescuento').html('(-10%)');
    console.log("hace el 10");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <span class="tipoDescuento"></span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diria que el fallo lo tienes en esta línea:

```
}else if(importe_base > 50 < 99){
```

que debería ser así:

```
}else if(importe_base > 50 && importe_base < 99){
```

Aún así, no soy muy amigo de los if anidados y me gusta más hacerlo con un switch lógico, de este modo:

```js
var importe_base = 105

switch (true) {
  case (importe_base <= 49):
    $('.tipoDescuento').html('Nada');
    console.log("no hace nada");
    break;
  case (importe_base > 50 && importe_base < 99):
    var calculo50 = importe_base * 5 / 100;
    descuento = calculo50;
    $('.tipoDescuento').html('(-5%)');
    console.log("hace el 5");
    break;
  case (importe_base >= 100):
    var calculo100 = importe_base * 10 / 100;
    descuento = calculo100;
    $('.tipoDescuento').html('(-10%)');
    console.log("hace el 10");
    break;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <span class="tipoDescuento"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola y gracias por tu respuesta, la verdad que yo también preferia hacerlo con switch lógico pero aun me salia peor. De todos modos a pesar de hacerlo así me sigue sucediendo lo mismo, el de más de 100 no lo reconoce

Comment: ¿has ejecutado mi respuesta?  A mi me sale lo del 10%... ¿no es eso lo que querias?

Comment: Lo he realizado tal como lo pones, pero mira he creado un JSFiddle y verás como no muestra bien tampoco, https://jsfiddle.net/opq3mnk8/3/

Comment: No, tu has puesto un OR (es decir, has usado `||`) y en mi respuesta yo uso un AND (es decir, `&&`)

Comment: Si lo cambie ahora, y veo que en JSFiddle si que funciona bien con &&, donde no funciona bien es en mi sitio

Comment: algo habrá en tu sitio distinto al jsfiddle o mi respuesta que estará entorpenciéndolo... quizas algun error en la consola?

Comment: No veo nada extraño, pero tu respuesta es la correcta. Mi variable `importe_base` se va actualizando en medida que se añaden o eliminan cosas del carrito, algo esta funcionando mal. Gracias por tu respuesta, voy a ver si encuentro la anomalia

Comment: Supongo que si ese importe_base es dinámico, en respuesta a algun evento, debes encerrar todo eso en una función para que la puedas ejecutar también en el mismo evento cada vez que el importe_base cambie.  Si tan solo la cargas durante la carga inicial de la página entonces no se va a reejecutar pongas lo que pongas. No se si me explico.

Comment: SI, tal cual como dices lo tengo, pero como se actualizan distintas cosas algo esta funcionado mal

Comment: Ok, entonces animos, jeje. sigue el código y lo encontraras :-)